# determine when an object only has certain properties

Tags: javascript

I'm creating an object that I'm using to carry to data back to the server via ajax.

Properties are added to the object based on the data that the server update should contain. Two of the properties are in every update object `FruitID` and `PeachID`

However, when an update object presents itself for an ajax call and only has these 2 properties, I want to cancel the call.

How can I determine that an object only contains certain properties?

Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: be warned, it looks like something is wrong in the architecture and logic you've chosen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var obj = {a:"property 1",b:"property 2"} // Or whatever object you want to check.

if(Object.keys(obj).length == 2     // If the object only has 2 keys,
    && obj["FruitID"]   // And FruitID exists as property of the object,
    && obj["PeachID"]){ // And PeachID exists as property of the object,
    // The object only contains FruitID & PeachID;
}
```

Or wrap it in an function:

```
function isBaseObject(obj){
    return !!(Object.keys(obj).length == 2 && obj["FruitID"] && obj["PeachID"]); // !! to cast the output to a boolean
}

isBaseObject({FruitID:"property 1",PeachID:"property 2"})
//true
isBaseObject({FruitID:"property 1",PeachID:"property 2", a:1})
//false
isBaseObject({a:1})
//false
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use [hasOwnProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty)

```
if (myObject.hasOwnProperty("FruitID")) { ... }
```

Another option might be to use `Object.keys`, but it's only supported in modern browsers. It'd be easier to do a comparison though, to see if only these properties exist.

Comment: You can't compare an array like that.

Comment: Yikes! You're right. Going to remove that part before I come back to edit, as I have to leave. Oops :(

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `hasOwnProperty`.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

```
o = new Object();
o.prop = 'exists';

o.hasOwnProperty('prop');   //returns true
```